# Cordova + File Transfer Upload Get stucks (stops) at 99% ( stops exactly 13 bytes before the total byte upload)

Tags: cordova, upload, file-transfer

I am building Android application using Cordova (Phonegap).

I use VideoUploadPlus plugin and FileTransfer plugins.

I am trying to upload the video that is captured to my webserver. The VideoUploadPlus works perfectly, it captures the video and I can get the path in Android device. But when I try to upload the file to server, it starts uploading and stops exactly when (Total-13) bytes are uploaded.

For example:
Uploaded: 
Current: 392530
Total: 392543

I checked chunkedMode parameter (tried either true or false), tried to specify trustAllHosts option, played with headers but nothing helps.

Callback functions are not invoked.

The code:

```
function uploadM(mediaFile) {


          var uri = encodeURI("http://MY_SERVER/upload.php");


          fileURL = mediaFile.fullPath.replace("file:/","");

          alert(fileURL);
          var options = new FileUploadOptions();
          options.fileKey="file";

          options.fileName=fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

          options.mimeType="video/mp4";

          var headers={'Content-Type':'video/mp4', 'Connection': 'close'};

          options.headers = headers;
          options.trustAllHosts = true;
          options.chunkedMode = false;

          var ft = new FileTransfer();

          alert(0);
          ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {

            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
              perc = parseInt((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) *100,10);

              $("#perc").html(perc+"%");
              $("#perc1").html(progressEvent.loaded+"");
              $("#perc2").html(progressEvent.total+"");
               if(perc==100){
               alert("Complete");
               }
            }

          }

          alert(uri);
          ft.upload(fileURL, uri, win, fail, options, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "win" function is called when the upload process is complete.  At that point, it's no longer calling  "onProgress", which is why it's not updating anymore.  What you'll want to do is update your win function to include the following:

```
$("#perc").html("100%");
alert("Complete");
```